# Find the MLE of $\theta$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Heights of certain animals are modelled using a normal distribution, with an unknown mean and a known standard deviation $\sigma=5$.
For a random sample of 20 animals, all that is known, is that 5 of them have a height greater than $5$.

Now, let $\theta$ be the probability that an animal's height is greater than $5$. Find the MLE of $\theta$.

I don't want a solution, please. I only want to be shown a start.

Answer (score 1):

You only want hints so here are some:

**Hints**: suppose that the heights of the animals are $H_1,\ldots,H_n$ (where $n=20$) each of which is identically and independently distributed as $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ ($\mu$ unknown, $\sigma=5$). Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be Bernoulli i.i.d. r.v.'s defined as $\Pr(X_i=1)=\Pr(H_i> 5)=\theta$ which is a function of $\mu$. Let's write $\theta=f(\mu)$. Then, 
$$
S=X_1+\cdots+X_n
$$ 
has a binomial distribution with mean $n\theta$ and variance $n\theta(1-\theta)$. The probability that $S\geq 5$ (or $S=5$, the wording of the problem is a bit unclear) is of course another function $\theta$ and so a function of $\mu$. Write $\Pr(S\geq 5)=h(\theta)=g(\mu)$ (or $\Pr(S=5)=h(\theta)=g(\mu)$ depending on how you interpret the problem). Find $\hat\mu$ that maximises $g$ and your answer is $f(\hat\mu)$.

In fact, you can directly find $\theta$ that maximises $h$ and **so the normality assumption isn't really needed.**

---

**Hints (part 2)**: if $h(\theta)=\Pr(S=5)$, then
$$
h(\theta)=\binom{20}{5}\theta^5(1-\theta)^{15}.
$$

Comment: I don't understand what you have done after defining $S$.

Comment: @user210292 $S$ counts the number of animals whose heights are greater than $5$.

Comment: And how does the fact that we already know 5 animals have  height greater than 5 come into play?

Comment: @user210292 If you mean that exactly $5$ animals have height greater than $5$ then $S=5$. If you mean that at least $5$ animals have height greater than $5$, then $S\geq 5$.

Comment: But how do I find $h(\theta)$??

Comment: @user210292 That's your challenge. You said you only wanted a nudge, didn't you? :)

Comment: let me try, because that is exactly where I have been facing the problem ever since.

Comment: @user210292 Read up about binomial distribution. Here is a good start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution.

Comment: What was the purpose of defining S? I really don't understand this question.

Comment: @user210292 I already explained $S$ above and provided other explanation. You said "I don't want a solution, please. I only want to be shown a start." I feel that you have received more than enough for a "start." Good luck.